# "undefined is not a function" onSuccessHandler

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have some problem in my datasource file, on line `onSuccessHandler( xmlRequest.responseText );`
here is the code

```
function initializeHttpRequest ( feedURL, onSuccessHandler, onErrorHandler ) {
    var onloadHandler = function( ) {
        if ( xmlRequest.readyState==4 && xmlRequest.status == 200 ) {
            onSuccessHandler( xmlRequest.responseText );
        }

     };
```

I use `initializeHttpRequest` in the following way:

```
initializeHttpRequest(httpfeed, onSuccess(), onFailure()); 
// where function onSuccess() { alert('true');} 
//       function onFailure() { alert('true');}
```

Any JSON service I call causing the error "undefined is not a function"
help needed, already spney sometime on it, and not familiar with it too..
Thanks

Comment: where is your `onSuccessHandler` ?

Comment: make sure that you pass onSuccessHandler function while calling initializeHttpRequest()

Comment: its not there... is it not the predefined func ?

Comment: @Adarsh:  initializeHttpRequest(httpfeed, onSuccess(), onFailure());
where
function onSuccess()
{ alert('true');}
function onFailure()
{  alert('true');}

Comment: @Fahad: You should always add new information to your actual post, not only in the comment.

Comment: ok, and Thanks Zeta...  will take care of it next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses. You're calling your functions instead of calling `initializeHttpRequest` with a reference to them:

```
initializeHttpRequest(httpfeed, onSuccess, onFailure);
//                                       ^^         ^^
```

Since both `onSuccess` and `onFailure` don't return any values, their return value is `undefined` and you get your error message.

Comment: Thanks Zeta, It worked and solved my problem..
one more thing i want to do, is to run an statement on success then  where to write it? an alert msg for example..

Comment: @Fahad: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX could help you. In general, you want to use your `responseText` in a sensible way: if it's HTML, you want to set the `innerHTML` of a node to it, if it's plain text you might want to show it somewhere else, and if it's JSON you might need to run it through `JSON.parse` first. Depends on your data. Your fragmnet isn't nearly large enough to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed onSuccess to onSuccess1 and made a function with the same name (onSuccess1) and alert in that, is this the right way ?
alert is working fine but not sure about the service..

Comment: @Fahad: Again, can't tell you, since I don't know any of your code. Maybe you should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide as well. Also if you have a question it's best to ask it, as the people in a comment discussion might miss your comment.